# Missing thumbnail image generating thumbnails on the fly

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Why if I generate many thumbnail images with the code below, during web page render some of them are always missing? I tested IE10 and FF21 and the missing image always change. We work with ASP.NET MVC 3.

Thanks.

```
WebImage wbImage = new WebImage("~/assets/images/gallery/"+imageName+".jpg");

int width = 220;

wbImage.Resize(width, (int)((double)wbImage.Height * width / wbImage.Width));

wbImage.FileName = imageName+"_small.jpg";

wbImage.Write();
```

Comment: I got similar issue with old IIS5 (on Win XP Home), where number of simultaneous requests was limited. I guess you should be looking into that.

Comment: Do you mean an IIS7 setting?

Comment: Yes; possibly there is also limit on operating system (max number of tcp connections). http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/limits

Comment: The page loads in less than one minute and the connection timeout default value is far above 60'

Comment: When you say "Why if I generate many thumbnail images with the code below, during web page render some of them are always missing?" are you saying that the code you have provided is running in your Render event? If not where is the code you have provided called from? Is it being run asynchronously? If you hit F5 and refresh the page does the image then appear?

Comment: The code above is inside a ASP.NET MVC action called once for every image in the gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to generate thumbnails on the fly if not present on disk and save them into `Thumbnail` folder. The next time you need them, read directly from disk.