# How do I check on disk if the thumbnail image is present and optionally use it in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

We are trying to generate image gallery thumbnail images programmatically in our ASP.NET MVC3 website instead of doing this manually all the times.

We are looking for implementing a function that checks in the TEMP folder is the thumbnail is present, otherwise creates and uses it.

Is a controller action the right place to implement this? What should this action return?

We already implemented the image generation on the fly with several problems when many thumbnail images are on the gallery page (some are always missing, because of too many hits?) and we'd like to try a different approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you not to create image/thumbnail generator yourself , but rather use http://imageresizing.net a C# library that has many advanced functions and plugins ( cahcing , creating thumbnails , dynamic resizing, etc, etc.)

Here is the NuGet url : http://nuget.org/packages/ImageResizer/

Here is a sample config i use

```
<resizer>
  <plugins>
    <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
    <add name="DiskCache" />
  </plugins>
  <diskCache dir="~/imagecache" autoClean="false" hashModifiedDate="true" enabled="true" subfolders="32" cacheAccessTimeout="3000" asyncWrites="false" asyncBufferSize="10485760" />
  <clientcache minutes="7200" />
</resizer>
```

Comment: I've heard about it but since we tried even caching without success I have the doubt that the problem is somewhere else. Do you have a sample webpage with many thumbnail images created on the fly to show me?

Comment: Alberto , the caching with ImageResizer can be a bit tricky, but it's deffinatly doable and not that hard , here is a sample : rush.bg/en/girls?categoryid=1  (disregard the slow loading of the page  there is a bug with the cms we use) if you want i can share configs with you.

Answer (score 0):

I would do such processing in a separate process, preferably Windows Service.

AppDomain can be recycled by IIS and your thumbnail processing thread may be killed in the middle of work. The same applies when the new version of the website is deployed or configuration changed.

Monitoring and maintenance of the background thread in IIS worker process would be probably more difficult than a separate Windows Service.

Comment: I'm not able to find any sources on the thread killing, can you provide any? AFAIK running requests are completed.

Comment: @Stijn - Is the thumbnail is processed synchronously, than yes. But if the processing is done by spawning a long-running background thread which will be monitoring TEMP folder, than this thread will be killed when AppPool recycles.

Comment: Do you understand exactly the reason why building images on the fly does not work correctly when the image number grows? I expected to see a page load delay but never missing images...

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would create an `ImageThumbnailService` or similar and expose it to your web app through an appropriate interface. That way, your application need only ask the service for a thumbnail and the service can do the worrying about whether or not the file exists, etc., calling off to some other class to create the thumbnail if it doesn't.

Comment: I still cannot understand the exact reason why building images on the fly does not work correctly when the image number grows.

Comment: Well, that would be entirely dependent on your code, which is completely absent from the question (and should probably be an altogether separate question to the one of architecture).

Comment: Here is the code, it's the body of a controller action: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105832/missing-thumbnail-image-generating-thumbnails-on-the-fly